Including a local PHP API that contains exit() statements
I have built a REST API in PHP that, in several cases, uses an exit() statement to prevent the script from continuing for various reasons.
This works well when I’ve been making calls to it using a JavaScript fetch.
I have now come across a case where I need to use this API in a PHP file on the same server. I know that I could use ‘include’, but this means that if an exit() statement is triggered, my entire script will stop running.
My API is quite extensive and so I’d prefer not to make edits to it (I know that I could replace exit with return for instance, but many of the exits in my API are called inside functions meaning that a return wouldn’t have the desired effect.)
Is there a better way to access my API in PHP than include? Or some way to get around this? Thank you.

Add a code snippet so the community can help you.

The crux of this question appears to be asking for advice on how to refactor multiple aspects of a codebase -- a codebase that we as volunteers cannot see.  Future readers will not be able to distinguish correct answers from incorrect answers because the question only contains generalized context. In the absence of concrete examples, this question leans toward being opinion-based about what is "best practice" for refactoring unwanted exit() calls.

I cant post an answer as the question is closed.  The simplest, fastest way is to define a variable in your caller file.  In the called file, you check for its existence, and dont execute exit.

@RohitGupta that could easily lead to situations where the script / function continues to run even when, logically, or for security purposes, it shouldn't. As the OP said, those exit() statements exist for specific reasons. An idea like that will need a bit more thought. Also, the OP wanted to avoid spending a lot of time refactoring. Your suggestion would require them to find all the places that exit() is used and add this extra logic.

You could treat it as an API and make a HTTP request to it using curl_exec or file_get_contents - that way you'd get basically the same experience as you do if you call it via fetch in your JS. It's a little bit less efficient than a direct include (because a HTTP request has a network overhead), but it avoids any refactoring and lets you treat it as a separate component or service, rather than something which needs integrating into other PHP scripts.
Obviously for more flexibility you'd refactor it so it has two interfaces, with shared business logic. So one bit is a class which performs the core functionality and you can instantiate it and call functions on it to get things done. Then the other bit is specifically to process incoming HTTP requests and respond to them - obviously it would make use of the separate class when needed in order to perform specific tasks. And if you have the class in a separate file, you could then just include that in other PHP scripts and use its functions directly without going via the web interface.

Thanks a lot for your quick response, I really appreciate it.
How inefficient is just using curl? Is this a common solution or is it generally considered that this isn’t really a good way of doing things?

@Liquidizer It's very common to use it to talk to other services. It's no more inefficient than using fetch or any other HTTP client. The main overhead compared to simply using include to run the code within the same script is the fact it uses network communication (even if the API service is actually on the same computer so that latency is almost 0, there is still a HTTP handshake and so on which needs to happen).

But I would suspect that unless the amount of data being transferred to/from the API is unusually large, and/or you will be doing thousands of simultaneous requests from PHP to this API, then you won't notice the difference.

@Liquidizer does it make any difference if you don't have another choice anyway?
